# How to add TextView from TextView ArrayList to the Layout of a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, android-fragments

I have this Fragment class:

```
import iumingv.android.physicalcontribution.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentDispositivi extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dispositivi, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
```

and this xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fa6a6a" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Dispositivi"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

if I want add many TextView from an ArrayList to the layout of the Fragment below,how can I do?

Comment: let me se if I've understood correctly, you want to programmatically add TextViews to that layout?

Answer (score 0):

I do think you should change the TextView in the RelativeLayout to ListView.
Then you can add all your textviews to the ListView

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the

   ```
   <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="Dispositivi"
      android:textSize="20dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
   ```

   to other file - let's say ui_textview
2. Then change the FragmentDispositivi:

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dispositivi, container, false);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
             View tv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ui_textview, container, false);
             rootView.add(tv);
        }
        return rootView;
   ```

   }

Another way is to use ListView for the same result.

Comment: The ArrayList<TextView> that I have,is dynamic,I add TextView or remove these,if I use an xml file as ui_textview,how can I add a new textview to the xml file o how to remove it?

Comment: the ui_textview is just a template. You can add or remove as many as you want textView. Use just use the xml file as template.

Comment: I don't undestand how can I add a new text input (from smartphone keyboard) as TextView on the xml file